# Consider a group $G$ with a finite normal subgroup $N$ with finite index. Is $G$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am solving a problem and only need solve the following question:

> Consider a group $G$ with a finite normal subgroup $N$ with finite index. Is $G$ finite?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $|G|=|G:N||N|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\lvert G\rvert=\lvert N\rvert [G:N],$$ where $[G:N]$ is the index of $N$ in $G$.